# webstorm переключение веток после изменений

Tags: webstorm

Раньше в том случае, если я сделал изменения и не закоммитил их, то webstorm не давал мне переключиться на другую ветку, была защита от дурака. Сейчас видимо случайно отключил ее. Не смог подобрать правильный запрос, чтобы найти ответ. Мб кто сталкивался с этим. VCS - git

Comment: aleksandr barakin, спасибо, действительно ошибся и не добавил "не", спасибо что вовремя написали об этом

Comment: уточните, какую именно vcs вы используете. потому что если речь о git, то программа git не даст этого сделать, вне зависимости от того, из какой gui-обёртки будет попытка это сделать.